Not able to use the extension in the SageMaker Studio Code Editor in VPC-only mode
I recently updated to the new experience of SageMaker Studio. When I opened the code editor, the extensions that are pre-installed in the official image were grayed out and unusable, as shown in the image below. Additionally, I cannot install new extensions.

My setup:

SageMaker Studio is in VPC-only mode.
It is associated with a private subnet.
The private subnet is connected to a NAT gateway, which is further connected to a VPC firewall that blocks communication with external domains, except for a few allowed ones.

Questions:

When I associated the subnet without a firewall, the extensions worked fine. Should I add anything to the firewall's allowlist to make the extensions work?
The firewall seems to be the main cause, but I believe the pre-installed extensions, like Python, should not require internet communication and should not be affected by the firewall. Are there any other settings I need to adjust?
On the extensions page, there are sections labeled "XXXX.sagemaker.aws-installed" and "browser-installed." Could the issue be that it is not connected to "sagemaker.aws"?

Other tries:

I pre-installed extensions in a custom image, but they do not work
properly either, exhibiting the same issues as mentioned above.
I also tried adding sagemaker.aws and .visualstudio.com to the
firewall's allowlist, but it did not resolve the issue.


Have you try adding https://open-vsx.org/ to do the firewall's allowlist? this is where the extensions are coming from.

You have to whitelist *open-vsx.org .All extensions do come from there according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/code-editor-use-connections-and-extensions.html
